# Why do people play a/h3?

Tags: opening, middlegame

I am very low rated in chess (900 chess.com rapid) and when I play against higher rated players I often see moves like h3, a3 from white, and the equivalent from black. I don't understand why someone would play these moves, as it doesn't exactly take the centre or develop pieces, threaten pieces etc. I often see it in the opening as well, when you are supposed to treat the tempo valuably and not throw it away with useless pawn moves.

Comment: It's a way too general question. Usually it's to prevent a piece from going to b4/g4, or preparation to play b2-b4 or g2-g4. But it could be anything really.

Comment: also many of these "higher rated players" are still going to be fairly bad (sub 2000) so they can play a3/h3 even when it isn't good or there isn't a clear reason

Answer (score 6):

@OP: Newcomers have a tendency to overgeneralize sensible hints.

a3/h3 is bad if

- it wastes time (*main reason*)
- it gives a hook for a pawn storm
- it generally weakens your castling position
- thousand other reasons having nothing to do with the general hint.

a3/h3 may be good if

- the reasons in the other answer
- it makes luft for the castled king
- thousand other reasons having nothing to do with the general hint.

Comment: an interesting question is why a6 is played early in QGD. and magnus also adds an early h6. is it to stop Bg5 or some other plan?

Comment: @ cmgchess - h6: I guess, yes. Note that you will never have to worry about d5 becoming shaky. a6: Expanding on the queenside is Black's plan anyway, usually after a delayed dxc4. b5 and Bb7 will follow.

Answer (score 2):

Some reasons why this might be done (answer assumes h3, flip it all for a3):

1. To prevent Bg4
2. To prevent Ng4 and allow stabily for a bishop on e3
3. To keep more pieces and cram the opponent
4. To prepare for g4

Answer (score 1):

You say

> I don't understand why someone would play these moves, as it doesn't exactly take the centre

These moves may be played to control the center.

For example, h3 may be play to prevent a Bishop landing on g4 which would pin a Knight on f3 weakening the knight's control of the center.